Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemException: malformed sequence in RSA private key
I encountered an error message stating "Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemException: malformed sequence in RSA private key" while working with RSA private keys in my application. What could be the potential causes of this error, and how can I troubleshoot and resolve it?
    private AsymmetricKeyParameter ReadPrivateKeyFromPemEncodedString()
    {
        AsymmetricKeyParameter result;
        
        string pemEncodedKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" + _mailSettings.DkimPrivateKey + "\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
        using (StringReader stringReader = new(pemEncodedKey))
        {
            PemReader pemReader = new(stringReader);
            object? pemObject = pemReader.ReadObject(); // Error occurs here
            result = ((AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pemObject).Private;
        }

        return result;
    }

  "MailSettings": {
    "AuthenticationRequired": false,
    "DkimPrivateKey": "TIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuPEN7GRYuHDiLovdnwASNmp8+VsMaHzejrkz4+RSzIp4eb+kIo+t0/sDYjkjplIkiXNeFmyn9/T4wFpEXhUqQ7GMkjbEim4z7uGKohcqY1BXBRYJF4qwjNoavN2/UxJOMy948foa+ww3VjC4IawYT4f7FdIAG/Lo1QbeJA8eJ0+cHUDIM6Rzn8BHSE7MO2jaeKdzSPCh3Pq7S3K35dRMBGy/t7YZ4LU+xb+Hzc9i5i9wySyuXrmKPSGEh+C7bcRSCpRDzIY5VPuK9KzLWWQYDBYt+XdpJr8+ySkroAB6TjpNAITG9faFBlyjYQG/mNK2YhT//WzYgpXsCOGFWS+1rQIDAQAB"
  }

